# Continuity and Infinite Sums

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, taylor-expansion

A well-known (and very useful) theorem in elementary topology states that the sum of two continuous functions is continuous. It can also be proven that any polynomial is continuous.

However, it is also well-known that many functions can be expressed as a MacLaurin Series, which is just an infinite polynomial with coefficients following certain constraints.

This is rather problematic to me. I want to prove that 
$$\cos x$$ is continuous, and I was planning on using this fact to do it. However, the existence of Maclaurin Series for functions like 
$$\frac{1}{1-x}$$
suggests that this is an invalid method of proof.

When can I use Maclaurin Series to prove continuity?

Comment: The result doesn't extend to infinite sums (for example, consider the repeated sum of $f(x) = x$). I'm not sure if there's any special cases where it does work, but at the very least the sum should be bounded for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @S.Ong So I can use it for cosine, since cosine is bounded?

Comment: The theorem you quoted in the first paragraph does not work for an *infinite* sum.

Comment: You just need to understand basic theorems about convergent power series.

Comment: The key concept is (locally) uniform convergence.

Comment: Wait. You know that $\cos x$ has Maclaurin series without knowing it's continuous? It doesn't make sense to prove it in this direction.

Comment: Any universitary book for a first course in calculus and mathematical analysis, if it covers the subject of power series, should be bound to cover appropriately the concept of "*uniform convergence* of a sequence of functions over a set", and to explain at least Hadamard's formula for the radius of convergence of a power series. Between those two things, there might be something like 50 pages (perhaps just 30). I strongly advise you to look for such a textbook in your local library and read the couple of chapters needed, instead of looking for a (probably lacking) summary of those facts.

Comment: @Adayah You can *define* $\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$. If you do that, then the question “Is $\cos$ continuous?” makes sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: but then by definition $\cos x$ is continuous everywhere. A power series is continuous wherever it converges (including end points of interval of convergence via Abel's theorem).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, not “by definition”. The fact that the sum of a power series is a continuous function is something the must be proved.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If you define $\cos$ as the power series, then the series is the definition of $\cos$, while it is not (yet known to be) the Maclaurin series of $\cos$. So it does make sense to prove continuity of $\cos$ from definition, but still doesn't make sense to prove it by the expansion to its Maclaurin series. Terminology matters here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: if one defines something via a series then it is obvious that one is aware of basic properties of a series. The case is similar to the fact that if one defines logarithm as an integral then one is aware of properties of integrals including fundamental theorem of calculus. If one is not aware of general properties of power series then using a definition based on that is a wrong idea. Things are defined in terms of things already well understood /known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the radius of convergence $r$ of a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is greater than $0$, then the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}(-r,r)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\x&\mapsto&\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\end{array}$$is continuous. In particular, since the radius of convergence of the series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$is $+\infty$, it defines a continuous function. And this function is the cosine function.

Comment: These are not Taylor's series.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: any power series with a positive radius of convergence is a Taylor series. What is your objection to the series in Jose's answer?

Comment: Taylor series has the form $P_n (x)+x^n\epsilon (x) $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Wrong. The [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$ of its domain is the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$.

Comment: It is a finite degree polynom $+$ an error. a power series is an infinite sum.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima False.  Series = infinite sum.  What you are mistaken with is Taylor's **theorem**, which is the finite version + error.

Answer (score 1):

From complex analysis, if a function of the form

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$

converges for all $|z|<R$ but for no $|z|>R$, then there exists a point $|z|=R$ such that $f(z)$ cannot be defined to be continuous at that point (and as far as complex functions go, it is undefined at that point).  Such a point is called a singularity.  Likewise, there cannot exist any singularities within the radius of convergence.  For $f(z)=\frac1{1-z}$, it is fairly obvious that it's Maclaurin expansion has radius of convergence $R=1$, so there exists a point $|z|=1$ such that $f(z)$ has a singularity.  That point happens to be $z=1$.  And $f(z)$ is continuous on $|z|<1$.

For a function such as $f(z)=\frac1{1+z^2}$, it is not obvious from a real standpoint that the Maclaurin expansion has radius of convergence $R=1$, however, from the above, it is easy to see that the function has singularities at $z=\pm i$, hence, $R=\min|\pm i|=1$.

Functions who's Taylor expansions have an infinite radius of convergence are called [entire functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function), and are continuous everywhere.

Comment: You must be using a non-standard concept of continuity. The function $f\colon D(0,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=\frac1{1-z}$ is continuous at every point of its domain. This remains true if you extend its domain to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$. Even then you cannot say that $f$ is discontinuous at $1$, since it isn't even defined there.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay, sure, I'll change that to remove the idea of $f$ being discontinuous at an undefined point.  But as to the other half of your comment, I never said that the function couldn't be continuous outside the radius of convergence, merely that it must have a singularity on the boundary of convergence.